# Arch Linux - Google Chrome Color Emoji

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, emoji

Is there a way to add color emoji to [Google Chrome](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-chrome/) on Arch Linux? 
Currently it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke13n.png)

Comment: Do you have `noto-fonts-emoji` installed?

Comment: I didn't, but when I do install them, ut messes with the text rendering on sites in Chrome and then words look too spaced apart